# Add-Migration results in InvalidOperationException error. What is the correct command?

Tags: c#, uwp, entity-framework-core

I was doing the tutorial from this website and stuck halfway.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started

I was stuck at this line

> Add-Migration MyFirstMigration

This are the errors that I get

> System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

It seems this error has been going on for some time but so far, Microsoft hasnt respond with a fix.

What should I do?

Comment: can you share the project?

Comment: Does your config have provider in entityFramework section?
Did you try to invoke Add-Migration with key **-ConnectionProviderName**?

Comment: I did exactly as the tutorial says.

Comment: As for the "Microsoft has not responded with a fix" part, the above exception comes when DbContext is not being configured properly with connection string which is mistake in user code. Therefore the error message clearly informs how to configure the context. As for tutorial, I will give it a try and if there is any errors in tutorial, I will make sure to get it updated. Thanks

Comment: While the error message clearly informs how to configure the context, it not clear enough for a newbie to do it. Also, why should I fix it myself? It is a Getting started article. What kind of prerequisite knowledge did you require? How can its a mistake in user code when I follow the guide the letter? Also, I'm not the only one that is having the same error. Its okay to make a mistake. But blaming others is not cool.

Answer (score 1):

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=yorudbname.db");

    }

    //ONLY necessary if you needing to use Fluent API
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder mb)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(mb);   //required reference comment - Order Matters as well.
                                    //ie has to be at the top.
```

now you will need to 2 other piece data in your project.json 1) `Design` 2) `Tools` listed below.

project.json

```
    "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.1",   <<required
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.3.1",  << must be 5.2.2 or higher
    "Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed": "2.0.0",
    "MvvmLight": "5.3.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "10.0.2",
    "Unity": "4.0.1"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.1" << required
```

don't pay any attention to the versions in this example **get the latest version available**.

make sure all that is correctly placed and recompile, might even have to close project and reopen, commands should run then.